# Do not allow "fake email" for registration

Tags: email, registration

We have a registration process where users can register with their email address. We do not want to allow to register with fake emails like 10minutemail, or equal. How can I implement that? Is there a blacklist for tose domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty comprehensive [list of temporary/disposable email domains](https://gist.github.com/adamloving/4401361). So depending on how you're handling the form submission, you might check against a list like that before processing the info for registration.

There are also some [email validation APIs](http://blog.mashape.com/post/69006514021/list-of-25-email-validation-apis) you might want to check out.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an email confirmation to the registration process. If you are worried about fake temporary emails, you can add a delay before confirmation email is sent.

Comment: Adding confirmation does not help as those services are designed to answer 'email confirmation' problem. Delaying isn't usually a good option as this will confuse users (they will not know if confirmation mail was sent or not)

Comment: I've already seen this on other pages. If you want to register with such an email address, you get an error message like "We do not support fake temporary emails". The question is basically how can I recognize those email addresses?